# HP all-in-one scanner software won't work

Tags: macos, hp-laserjet, osx-tiger, all-in-one

I have an HP LaserJet M1212NF MFP All-in-One connected to my father's PowerMac G5 running OS X Tiger.

It worked fine for the three months he's had it, but now when he tries to scan something, everything in the scanning software's window is dimmed (there is no physical button to scan). I tried reinstalling the software and the printer's firmware but that did nothing.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Try the HP Scan Diagnostic software....http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c02073861&jumpid=ex_r4155/hho/ipg/ccdoc/trailhead_doc&lang=en

Comment: Does it print ok? If it's connected via USB, is it visible in the USB section of the System Profiler application?

Comment: It prints fine and is visible in the USB section.

Answer (score 0):

Suspect an Apple update — has your father still got access to
1) the G5 MacOS 10.4 discs?
2) the original printer/scanner software discs?
3) a firewire connected hard disc big enough to backup his system?

If yes to all so, use Carbon Copy Cloner© to make a bootable clone and then (and only after checking he can boot from the clone) delete from the original disk all references to HP software, both printing and scanning. Then do a re-install from the original CD offline. See if that works. If so, switch off automatic updates.

I've had to do this with a clamshell iBook running OS10.3

Good luck
Paul

Comment: 1) maybe 2) yes 3) yes. Will try that.